# Using Freestyle with semi-transparent materials

Tags: cycles-render-engine, freestyle

I am working on an animation which will have a model behind transparent materials making up the foreground:

[image: Axonometric of model]

However, no Freestyle settings ("QI Range", etc.) are working for me. I tried setting "Edge Mark" and "Exclusive", but depending on the "Visibility" setting I either get the lines showing through the foreground mesh or being entirely hidden by that mesh.

What would be the optimal way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Via Carlo's comment above (linking to [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41399/can-freestyle-draw-lines-when-an-object-is-behind-a-transparent-plane)), it appears that in Blender, "transparent faces are treated as opaque faces," so my setup would not work. Instead, I will separate the Freestyle layer.